# Php array dynamic fill

Tags: php, arrays

how can i fill following type array dynamicly in for loop

```
   array('items'=>array(
array('label'=>'News', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
array('label'=>'News2', 'url'=>array('/site/2')),
));
```

I am new in programming

thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array();

for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $arr[] = array(
        'label' => 'News'.($i > 1 ? $i : ''),
        'url' => $i == 1 ? '/site/index' : '/site/'.$i
    )
}

$result = array('items' => $arr);
```

And the resulting array will be in the form:

```
array('items' => array(
    array(
        'label' => 'News',
        'url' => '/site/index'
    ),
    array(
        'label' => 'News2',
        'url' => '/site/2'
    ),
    array(
        'label' => 'News3',
        'url' => '/site/3'
    ),
    array(
        'label' => 'News4',
        'url' => '/site/4'
    )
));
```

..depending on the `$count` variable.

Answer (score 2):

`for($i = 0; $i < $items; $i++) { //where $items is number of news items
    if($i == 0)
        $value = "Index";
    else
        $value = $i+1;
    $ar["items"]["News".$i] = $value;
}`

You can access the array by square brackets, by both alphanumerical and purely numerical keys. Anyway I suggest reading a basic php course.

Answer (score 0):

use for to loop like :

```
$items=array();
for($i=1;$i<=$max_count;$i++){
$element = array('label'=>'news'.$i,'url'=>'/site/index'.$i);
$items[] = $element;
}
```

Comment: what you want in your entries ?